# Chromium will not load on Ubuntu 14.04 after machine was accidentally unplugged. How to fix it?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, chromium

I moved my HP Pavilion 23, accidentally unplugging it while a video was playing on Youtube using Google Chrome browser.

When I tried to re-open chrome, the icon would go from light to dark for several seconds, then go back to its unselected look, and Chrome never opened.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and am new to adding/deleting programs, or tweaking Ubuntu.

Comment: Is it definitely chrome, not chromium? Chromium is in the ubuntu repos (actually a slightly outdated version for 14.04) but for either, open a terminal and type `chrom` and then press TAB a few times, it should autofill whichever you've got or list options. Run the browser command in the terminal and see what it says (probably some profile corruption I'm guessing)

Comment: Thank you Xeno2050.  I am so new to this that I just learned how to get the command line.  I still do not know how to edit the command line, nor do I have any programming experience

Comment: It's not really "programming", but if you're in the right window (run "terminal" from the start / programs menu) you should see something like "`ubuntu@xubuntu:~$`" and you can type anything. Google & Youtube should know how to open a terminal in ubuntu, it's a little different with xubuntu, lubuntu, kubuntu, etc, a video might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen and fixed it today.  And yes, it says Chromium.

After trying the usual remedies I found all over the web such as navigating into various local directories and clearing out files, etc., it still wouldn't work.

I couldn't even uninstall it and try a reinstall because I didn't know the package name.

So here is what worked:

Go into the Ubuntu Software Center (Press the Windows key and type "soft" and it will find it)

Search for Chromium - It found it when I typed just "chro"

I told it to uninstall it.  Took just a minute or two.

Once uninstalled, I rebooted.

Then I went back into the Ubuntu Software Center, searched for it again then told it to install it.

It did so.

And it worked.

Then when I logged it back into Google (from the Settings menu) it restored my extensions and bookmarks and everything.  (The former Chromium wouldn't connect to Chrome settings but they have updated it so it works fine now)

Now it is acting normal.